# Combine Array with Json in PhP

Tags: arrays, json, match, indexof

I am having an API that is getting data's in Json format. 

[
      {
              "id": "bitcoin", 
              "name": "Bitcoin", 
              "symbol": "BTC", 
              "rank": "1", 
              "price_usd": "7365.07", 
              "price_btc": "1.0", 
              "24h_volume_usd": "4900640000.0", 
              "market_cap_usd": "124873929597", 
              "available_supply": "16954887.0", 
              "total_supply": "16954887.0", 
              "max_supply": "21000000.0", 
              "percent_change_1h": "0.55", 
              "percent_change_24h": "5.92", 
              "percent_change_7d": "-7.93", 
              "last_updated": "1522733968", 
              "price_eur": "5987.30108524", 
              "24h_volume_eur": "3983887076.48", 
              "market_cap_eur": "101514013335"
        }, 
        {
              "id": "ethereum", 
              "name": "Ethereum", 
              "symbol": "ETH", 
              "rank": "2", 
              "price_usd": "397.12", 
              "price_btc": "0.0541563", 
              "24h_volume_usd": "1216740000.0", 
              "market_cap_usd": "39149486407.0", 
              "available_supply": "98583517.0", 
              "total_supply": "98583517.0", 
              "max_supply": null, 
              "percent_change_1h": "0.07", 
              "percent_change_24h": "3.51", 
              "percent_change_7d": "-15.33", 
              "last_updated": "1522733953", 
              "price_eur": "322.83155584", 
              "24h_volume_eur": "989126881.68", 
              "market_cap_eur": "31825870284.0"
         }
   ]

On the other hand, I am having Object array

```
Array
```

(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 42
            [user_id] => 39
            [coin_rank] => 2
        )

```
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 3
        [user_id] => 39
        [coin_rank] => 6
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 8
        [user_id] => 39
        [coin_rank] => 8
    )
```

)

I want only Json array that match coin rank array key **coin_rank** from array index value.

**like get only ethereum array if rank and coin rank matched. else neglected**

Sorry if you didn't get my point, Ask me without hesitation.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run a loop and find `rank` key in json array.

```
       $jsonArr = json_decode($json, true);
       $new = array();
       foreach($arr as $v){
           $key = array_search($v->coin_rank, array_column($jsonArr, 'rank'));
           if($key !== false){
               $new[] =  $jsonArr[$key];
           }
       }
       print_r($new);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/CU1AJ)